# Forecasting in R with time-series when one of the future variables is pre-defined

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I'm relatively new to R programming, but I've been reading your blogs and posts in order to learn more about time-series However, I have been struggling how to proceed.

The data is per month per customer per product. Moreover, it is specified if there has been a campaign or not that specific month for that specific customer and product.

I would like to forecast the sales for the next X months based on the known "Campaign (T/F)".

Which R model / package would you recommend to look into?

The time-series is stored in a data frame like this:

```
Date    Customer    Product Campaign (T/F)  Sales

01/01/2023  CustomerA   Product1    1   159

01/02/2023  CustomerA   Product1    0   123

01/03/2023  CustomerA   Product1    0   101

01/04/2023  CustomerA   Product1    0   114

01/05/2023  CustomerA   Product1    0   123

01/06/2023  CustomerA   Product1    0   105

01/07/2023  CustomerA   Product1    1   148

01/01/2023  CustomerA   Product2    0   85

01/02/2023  CustomerA   Product2    0   93

01/03/2023  CustomerA   Product2    1   145

01/04/2023  CustomerA   Product2    0   88

01/05/2023  CustomerA   Product2    0   91

01/06/2023  CustomerA   Product2    1   148

01/07/2023  CustomerA   Product2    1   137
```

I have been reading on time-series and going through the Question section in Stack overflow